# Heroku github deploying fail- angular app

Tags: angular, heroku, deployment

I have angular app whose I want to deploy with Heroku, I built my project locally with the command:

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build
```

and every thing works fine.
I run my project locally with the command:

```
node server.js
```

then I tried to deployed the app by heroku - github
and when I tried to deploy branch I got an error, this is the log of the error:

```
-----> Node.js app detected
   
-----> Creating runtime environment
   
   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
   
-----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
   
   Resolving node version 12.x...
   Downloading and installing node 12.18.2...
   Using default npm version: 6.14.5
   
  -----> Installing dependencies
   Installing node modules
   
   > fsevents@1.2.12 install /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
   > node-gyp rebuild
   
   make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build'
     SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/.node
     COPY Release/.node
   make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents/build'
   
   > fsevents@1.2.12 install /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
   > node-gyp rebuild
   
   make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents/build'
     SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/.node
     COPY Release/.node
   make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents/build'
   
   > core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/core-js
   > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
   
   
   > @angular/cli@9.1.1 postinstall /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/angular-datatables/node_modules/@angular/cli
   > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
   
   
   > @angular/cli@9.1.4 postinstall /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/@angular/cli
   > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
   
   
   > core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
   > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
   
   
   > igniteui-cli@5.0.1 postinstall /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/igniteui-cli
   > node ./scripts/install.js
   
   
   > tsp-project-ui@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105
   > ng build --prod
   
   Warning: Entry point 'agm-direction' contains deep imports into '/tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
   Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/observers : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/a11y : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/core : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/overlay : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/form-field : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/layout : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/button : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/flex-layout/core : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/text-field : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/icon : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/input : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/select : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/tooltip : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @agm/core : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/flex-layout/extended : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/flex-layout/flex : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/flex-layout/grid : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling ngx-progressbar : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/dialog : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/accordion : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/divider : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/stepper : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/table : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/paginator : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/sort : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/tree : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/core/testing : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/platform-browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/common/testing : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/flex-layout : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/animations/browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/clipboard : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/cdk/drag-drop : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/common/http/testing : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/autocomplete : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/badge : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/bottom-sheet : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/button-toggle : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/card : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/checkbox : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/chips : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/datepicker : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/expansion : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/grid-list : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/icon/testing : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/list : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/menu : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/progress-bar : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/progress-spinner : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/radio : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/sidenav : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/slide-toggle : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/slider : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/snack-bar : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/stepper : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/table : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/tabs : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/toolbar : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material/tree : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/material-moment-adapter : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular/router/testing : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling agm-direction : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling angular-datatables : module as esm5
   Warning: Unable to fully load /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/angular-datatables/src/angular-datatables.directive.js for source-map flattening: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/angular-datatables/src/angular-datatables.directive.js.map'
   Warning: Unable to fully load /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/angular-datatables/src/angular-datatables.module.js for source-map flattening: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/angular-datatables/src/angular-datatables.module.js.map'
   Warning: Unable to fully load /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/angular-datatables/index.js for source-map flattening: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/node_modules/angular-datatables/index.js.map'
   Compiling angularx-social-login : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling igniteui-angular : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling ng2-file-upload : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling ngx-perfect-scrollbar : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling ngx-progressbar/http : es2015 as esm2015
   Compiling ngx-progressbar/router : es2015 as esm2015
   
   WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/src/app/AuthenticationManagement/dashboard/dashboard.component.css. Budget 6 kB was not met by 154 kB with a total of 160 kB.
   
   WARNING in Exceeded maximum budget for /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/src/app/AuthenticationManagement/login/login.component.css. Budget 6 kB was not met by 154 kB with a total of 160 kB.
   
   ERROR in src/app/AuthenticationManagement/register/register.component.ts:23:14 - error NG6007: The Component 'RegisterComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.
   
   23 export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   
     src/app/app.module.ts:105:5
       105     RegisterComponent,
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       'RegisterComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule'.
     src/app/services/Module/authentiction/authentiction.module.ts:14:5
       14     RegisterComponent
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       'RegisterComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AuthentictionModule'.
   src/app/AuthenticationManagement/login/login.component.ts:18:14 - error NG6007: The Component 'LoginComponent' is declared by more than one NgModule.
   
   18 export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   
     src/app/app.module.ts:104:5
       104     LoginComponent,
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       'LoginComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule'.
     src/app/services/Module/authentiction/authentiction.module.ts:13:6
       13      LoginComponent,
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       'LoginComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AuthentictionModule'.
   
   ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/src/app/AuthenticationManagement/dashboard/dashboard.component.css. Budget 10 kB was not met by 150 kB with a total of 160 kB.
   ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for /tmp/build_3c5cb0395de8e0d3963273d354182105/src/app/AuthenticationManagement/login/login.component.css. Budget 10 kB was not met by 150 kB with a total of 160 kB.
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! tsp-project-ui@0.0.0 postinstall: `ng build --prod`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR! 
   npm ERR! Failed at the tsp-project-ui@0.0.0 postinstall script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
   
   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.BHvwU/_logs/2020-07-07T08_57_23_736Z-debug.log
    -----> Build failed
   
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   Some possible problems:
   
   - Node version not specified in package.json
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
   
   Love,
   Heroku
   
   !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
   !     Push failed
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

LoginComponent and RegisterComponent are declared in two Modules (AuthentictionModule and AppModule). To solve this you must declare those components in one of those modules, just one not in both. After that you can try an `ng build` locally to check if there's additional errors. Also if you build at Heroku as production mode you can check locally with `ng build --prod`.